# Design concerns about Page Object Model Pattern

Tags: selenium, testing, design-patterns, browser-automation

I wonder if something is wrong with our approach to the POM. In many examples on the internet I find this pattern used in a way so that your test script looks like this:

```
pageObject.doSomethingWithElement(parameters...)
```

For us it was more natural to do it like this:

```
pageObject.element.doSomething(parameters...)
```

So we don't need to implement what can be done with an element in the page class but just simply define those actions in the test script. For some reason that felt more natural for us similar to the fact that there is

```
System.out.println()
System.err.println()
```

instead of

```
System.printlnOut()
System.printlnErr()
```

Do we miss some disadvantage of our approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no advantage or disadvantage when choosing between those 2 models. But I think you are slightly misunderstanding the recommended approach. The idea is not to `pageObject.doSomethingWithElement`, but to do something with a functionality of the page, `pageObject.doSomething` if you want.

If you look at [Selenium examples](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) for instance, one of the first examples is `public HomePage loginAs(String username, String password)`. Nothing in this function is about elements, it's about functionality of the page, easily expressed verbally, without any reference to elements involved. I can read this function as: *when user is on Login page, and user provides username and password, on successful login, user is redirected to Home Page*. Which sort of provides a natural BDD interpretation of page model.

The advantage of such approach is that your tests are much more readable. Instead of something like:

```
loginPage.username.setValue(...)
loginPage.password.setValue(...)
loginPage.loginButton.submit()
// how do I get a homepage from here?
```

this model allows to have

```
HomePage homePage = loginPage.loginAs(...)
```

Done!

Also from maintenance perspective: if developers change elements on Login page, it might be important for 20 tests that deal with login functionality. But you want other 980 tests you have to be completely unaffected by their change, since they only use login on their way to test other parts of functionality. So they can remain completely oblivious to changes in login elements, as long as login itself keeps working as it should.

So I think the choice is not between various ways your page could express element-related functions, but with whether your page should express elements at all, or concentrate on functionality it provides, regardless of the elements.

I recommend reading that page I quote here, it gives a very good idea of what page model is all about.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this explanation. I was not able to see this in the most of the times simple examples. But your point totally makes sense!

Comment: Great answer; you took the words right out of my mouth!  +1.

Comment: FWIW, at the beginning of your answer you state these is no advantage or disadvantage, however at the end you explain a huge advantage that shows why people choose to make the test scripts unaware of elements on the page. That being said I understand the language is to suggest that there might be advantages of the other approach as well that probably shouldn't be dismissed.

Comment: @ mrfreester top of the answer says that there's no advantage or disadvantage between `pageObject.doSomethingWithElement` and `pageObject.element.doSomething`, since they both deal with elements. The rest of the answer describes advantages when you don't deal with elements at all

Comment: I would argue that you aren't following the page object model if you are exposing the elements of the page themselves. You should be providing "services" or "actions" of that page and leave the internals of the page structure hidden from the consumer.

Comment: @JeffC I wouldn't argue with you, selenium page model was develop with that meaning in mind. But if you look at tutorials, examples and so on you can find with "selenium page model" search, you can see that a lot of them (even from reasonably trusted sources) are built on elements, so I see where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: @JeffC out of curiosity I checked 1st 10 links for "selenium page model", and 5 of them were demoing element-based approach, only 2 were talking about actions/services/functional approach (2 more were from selenium itself, and 1 didn't work at all)

Comment: @KirilS. That doesn't really surprise me. I'm not sure what I would expect when googling "selenium page model" unless it was specific to "page object model", which is the actual name. There is a lot of bad/confusing/misguided info on the web about it.